How would you add a new line after redirecting a command's output using >> in Bash?
read -r -p "Enter process name: " childpid 
apid=$(pgrep "$childpid")
ps -p "$apid" # process-specific information
read -r -p "Log process info [yes/no] " log
   if [[ $log == "yes" ]]
     then 
      ps -p "$apid" >> pslog.txt # logging process-specific information
   fi

Basically, when I rerun the script the information just stacks in a way that looks ugly. I want to add a new line each time the script is run before any information is logged.
I tried to echo before and after ps -p "$apid" >> pslog.txt but it didn't work. I'm using Cygwin if that matters.

You mean a blank line between commands? echo >>pslog.txt should do it.

Or { ps -p "$apid"; echo; } >>pslog.txt to only open the output file once -- using a grouping that way is more efficient than putting >>pslog.txt on each of two separate commands. (Note that the syntax used there is very deliberate -- the ; before the last } is essential when running this as a one-liner; so is the space after the {)

{ ps -p "$apid"; echo; } >>pslog.txt worked! Thanks! Is the lack of space between >> and pslog.txt also deliberate?
